# OpenStack instances do not update

Tags: instance, wget, openstack, apt-get

I have a critical situation.

I installed openstack in multinode servers (controller, network, compute1, compute2). Everything works fine except when it comes to update instances using    `apt-get update`.

I am getting this error: `98% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]`.

Guest instances are: `Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS`

I can ping any server over the internet, but no other operations can be done.

Also I am getting this error when using `wget`: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`

I have enabled all protocols in default security group:

```
# nova secgroup-list-rules default
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| IP Protocol | From Port | To Port | IP Range  | Source Group |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+
|             |           |         |           | default      |
| tcp         | 80        | 80      | 0.0.0.0/0 |              |
| tcp         | 443       | 443     | 0.0.0.0/0 |              |
|             |           |         |           | default      |
| tcp         | 53        | 53      | 0.0.0.0/0 |              |
| icmp        | -1        | -1      | 0.0.0.0/0 |              |
| tcp         | 22        | 22      | 0.0.0.0/0 |              |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

I hope you can assist me in this problem.

I tried creating my own images and I tested them before importing them to openstack they work fine, but once uploading them to openstack and creating instances they do not perform these operations.

====(updated)=====

Hi alvits, I put all tcp and udp ports (ingress and egress) enabled
and this is the output:

```
# neutron security-group-rule-list | grep egress
| 007de1d1-ef92-414d-8796-fff0f124a359 | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
| 45738919-bdf2-4cb5-a367-0ee1fcabc4fb | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
| 6bf70074-5673-4098-85d7-07630d9a09ed | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
| 75ae039b-d0e6-4f32-a2e1-4e3616597079 | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
| 92f7477a-db31-4fab-bf72-de455ce9f61a | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
| a8bf452b-9de4-441e-9785-951819247018 | default        | egress    |          |                  |              |
```

=======(New update)======

I noticed weird thing, I tried `wget` with some small pdf files from google and it's downloaded smoothly, however when trying to download large files they give `HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`

Comment: I don't think you defined any outgoing rule. Can you add the output of `neutron security-group-rule-list | grep egress`?

Comment: I have run into that issue where downloading large files via `curl` or `scp` fails with `corrupted packet`. `dmesg` on the network node shows udp corrupted messages. I resolved it by upgrading the kernel. If your kernel is recent, try setting `generic-receive-offload` to `off` on the physical interface of the external bridge.

Comment: If your issue has anything to do with `generic-receive-offload` you can try this simple test. Put a large iso file on your network node and try to copy it from one of the instances. The copy will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Thank you alvits for your efforts and support,
since only large files didn't work, I thought this might be a problem with the MTU size

so I followed [OpenStack Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/yum/content/neutron-ml2-network-node.html), which solves the problem:

Here is the solution:

1. edit: `/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini` 
   and added the following line: 
   `dnsmasq_config_file = /etc/neutron/dnsmasq-neutron.conf`
2. created a new file: `/etc/neutron/dnsmasq-neutron.conf`
   and added the following line:
   `dhcp-option-force=26,1454`
3. run:`killall dnsmasq
   service neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart
   service neutron-dhcp-agent restart
   service neutron-l3-agent restart
   service neutron-metadata-agent restart
   service dnsmasq restart`
4. reboot the instance

That's it and it's working. Now I can use `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` 
and `wget` .